How to merge a branch from a repo to a branch of a fork
Context:

I have a git repo named "gitcode"
I have a forked repo named "gitcode_forked"

And I want to merge the branch "gitcode\develop" into "gitcode_forked\develop"
From what I what I see the Merge command of GitLib2Sharp doesn't have a implementation with 2 different repo ... also the repository is set with a using block ...
    using (var repo = new Repository(repoDirectory))
    {
        var masterBranch = repo.Branches["master"];
        var developBranch = repo.Branches["develop"];
        var merger = new Signature(AuthorName, AuthorEmail, DateTime.Now);

        Commands.Checkout(repo, masterBranch);
        repo.Merge(developBranch, merger, new MergeOptions());

        repo.ApplyTag("v0.1");

        Commands.Checkout(repo, developBranch);
        repo.Merge(masterBranch, merger, new MergeOptions());
    }


I haven't done this directly with GitLib2Sharp, but what you need to do is add a git remote branch to the repo in question.  This is what I'd do, but only because the two branches have the same name:

Let's assume that repo "gitcode" is set up as remote name "origin" and repo "gitcode_forked" is set up as remote name "fork"
Rename your local branch 'develop' to 'develop_src'
Do a pull of the develop branch of gitcode_forked by using its remote name "fork"
Merge local 'develop_src' into local 'develop'
Push local 'develop' back to remote name 'fork'

This would be much easier if the branches were named differently on the two repositories.  This approximates how you'd do it.  If I were you, I would do this manually once to understand the steps.  If you are using Visual Studio,
I don't know of any built in options for setting up remote repos -- you'll have to use the command line, or another GUI tool like TortoiseGit.
Best of luck.
